# fetchall for loop multiple list to one

Tags: python, django

I have followings in my django:

My models.py

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import dateutil
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, WEEKLY, MO, SU
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.db import connections

class WeeklyReports(models.Model):
    def FourWeeks(self, year, week):
        self.year = year
        self.week = week
        end = datetime(year, 1, 1) + relativedelta(weeks=week-1, weekday=SU)
        start = end - relativedelta(weeks=4, weekday=MO)
        mint, maxt = datetime.min.time(), datetime.max.time()
        for dt in rrule(WEEKLY, start, count=4):
            yield dt.combine(dt, mint), dt.combine(dt + timedelta(days=6), maxt)
```

views.py:

```
import itertools
from itertools import chain, groupby
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from datetime import datetime 
from weeklyreport.models import WeeklyReports
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import connections

def WeekCombo(request):
    fweeks = []
    cursor = connections['nocdb'].cursor()
    year = 2013
    week = 48
    w = WeeklyReports()
    for start, end in w.FourWeeks(year, week):
        cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT (p.name) AS platform, count(e.id ) AS count FROM event e, lu_platform p WHERE e.platform_id = p.id AND e.sourcetype_id = 1 AND e.event_datetime BETWEEN %s AND %s AND e.sender_id  NOT IN ( 759, 73 ) GROUP BY p.name ORDER BY p.name", [start, end] )
        r = [i for i in chain.from_iterable(cursor.fetchall())]
        fweeks.append([n for n in r])
    return render_to_response('form.html', {'fweeks': fweeks}, 
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

With my fetchall loop I get four lists:

```
[u'Cust01', 191L, u'Cust02', 21L, u'Cust03', 420L]
[u'Cust01', 17L, u'Cust02', 96L, u'cust03', 11L]
[u'Cust01', 44L, u'Cust02', 225L, u'Cust03', 356L]
[u'Cust01', 76L, u'Cust02', 304L, u'Cust03', 157L, u'Cust04', 212L]
```

I the way to make from this four separated query list one nested list? How I can merge this lists in loop?

```
[['Cusr01','Cust02','Cust03', 'Cust04'], [191, 21, 420], [17, 96, 11], [44, 225, 356],
[76, 304, 157, 121]]
```

Comment: First, `[i for i in foo]` isn't doing anything; it's just the same thing as `list(foo)`. And then you do it again, with `[n for n in r]`, where `r` is just the result of `[i for i in foo]` above. You're just making a copy of a copy of a list for no good reason. What were you _trying_ to do with those lines?

Comment: Second, `fetchall` returns an iterable of rows, each of which is an iterable of columns. `chain.from_iterable` turns that into a flat iterable of columns. You're already done. Each thing you append to `fweeks` is already flattened. Which means `fweeks` ends up as a list of flat lists. Which is exactly what you're asking for. So… what's the problem here?

Comment: Finally, when you say "With my fetchall loop I get four lists", _where_ do you get those lists? The only `fetchall` loop in your code is the one hidden inside `chain.from_iterable`, or maybe the useless extra one inside the list comprehension. So, yes, each `i` is a single flat list, but what else would you expect it to be, and how are you viewing it in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for your response, Indeed there was copy of copy list, How I can merge the unique names in first list and values from each query in next lists?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for in that last comment. I still can't see what problem you're having in the first place. Show us code that actually generates the output you're asking about (ideally stripped-down, _runnable_ code that doesn't require access to your database and other functions you haven't shown us—see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for guidance), and tell us what output you want instead, and where, from that code. Then your question will be answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to transpose a set of lists in this format:

```
data = [[x, y], [x, y], [x, y]]
```

into this format:

```
[[x, x, x], [y, y, y]]
```

you can use the built-in `zip` function:

```
results = zip(data)
```

Thus, your code would become:

```
def WeekCombo(request):
    fweeks = []
    cursor = connections['nocdb'].cursor()
    for start, end in WeeklyReports().FourWeeks(2013, 48):
        cursor.execute("""
            SELECT DISTINCT (p.name) AS platform,
                COUNT(e.id ) AS count
            FROM event e, lu_platform p
            WHERE e.platform_id = p.id
            AND e.sourcetype_id = 1
            AND e.event_datetime BETWEEN %s AND %s
            AND e.sender_id  NOT IN ( 759, 73 )
            GROUP BY p.name
            ORDER BY p.name""", [start, end] )
        fweeks.extend(cursor.fetchall())
    fweeks = zip(fweeks)
    return render_to_response('form.html', {'fweeks': fweeks}, 
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thank you, your code is much elegant.  With this I get list of tuples.

((u'Cust01', 191L),)
((u'Cust02', 21L),)
((u'Cust03', 420L),)
((u'Cust04', 150L),)
((u'Cust01', 96L),)
((u'Cust02', 11L),)
((u'Cust03', 388L),)
((u'Cust01', 44L),)
((u'Cust02', 225L),)
((u'Cust03', 356L),)
.... end so

Comment: And with following fweeks = list((zip(*fweeks))) I able to split names and values.

(u'Cust01', u'Cust02', u'Cust03', u'Cust04'...u'Cust01', u'Cust02', u'Cust03', u'Cust04')
(191L, 21L, 420L, 150L, 759L, 290L ....403L, 556L, 130L, 12L, 973L)

What I taring to do is build charts with googlecharts and I need the list in followings format:
[['Cusr01','Cust02','Cust03', 'Cust04'], [191, 21, 420], [17, 96, 11], [44, 225, 356],
[76, 304, 157, 121]]
Or maybe is better format my list in template?